# Trying to read strings from .txt file into string array using fscanf, worked with ints but not strings. Segfault

Tags: c

I'm trying to read numbers from a text file as strings then put them into an array. I initially had an integer array and was reading with fscanf with data type "%d". That worked fine, but I would like to read the numbers as strings instead.

So I've created the nums array, and I'm trying to have fscanf read strings into the nums array. (The reason the array is a fixed size is because my assignment dictates this).

The code compiles without any warnings, but the first attempt to read "%s" into nums[y] creates a segmentation fault.

The txt file I'm opening into fp is somewhat as follows: "83222 331111 335533 33222 33333..." with about 5000 numbers with a space between each one.

```
char *nums[76*76];
int y = 0;
while (fscanf(fp,"%s",nums[y]) == 1){
   y++;
}
```

Comment: You want something like `char nums[5000][16]`

Comment: You've got 5776 pointers, but none of them point anywhere.  You may have thought that `char *` was C's "string" type, but it's more complicated than that.

Comment: The `scanf()` family is not really a good choice to read strings, read carefully the documentation for "%s". Take a look at `fgets()` and `strtok()` to read the lines of the file (you didn't mention how many lines the files has) and to divide them into parts at the blanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SIGSEV on strcpy to a char pointer](//stackoverflow.com/q/56815108/90527)